# Is there a way to import external data into Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Other than EOD data, is there a way to import more frequent external data into pinescript? I have some custom calculations I'd like to show on the chart.

I know of the EOD seed approach, but I want to import data that is on a smaller timeframe